# Set page load to black instead of white background?

Tags: html, css, load, flickr

Link to website:

http://www.ideagang.co/home.php

Is it possible to set the background to black when click from 1 page to another? 
Right now the website load perfectly with the black background, it's just that when I navigate from one page to another the page flickr for a second.....

Is there anyway to resolve this by setting the background to black when loading page internally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not using only CSS. The browser's default color for the background is white, so the flicker you see is the default coming through for a split second before it has a chance to read the CSS rule to make it black.

The only way I can think of to get around this would be to load the first page, and then switch from page to page via javascript, loading them in to the exiting page. No reloads means no flicker. In my opinion, that is a ton of overhead for very little value, so I would suggest just living with it.

Answer (score 1):

I very much doubt this would be possible with CSS.

Have you tried using

```
<body background="#000">
```

It is long deprecated but may help. I think you will still get a white flash but it may be for less time.

You could also try putting a small block of CSS as the first thing in the header after your title.

Answer (score 0):

the html5 method of doing this via CSS is now:

```
<body style="background-color:#000">
```

also tried putting this CSS styling as the first thing in the `<head>` :

```
<style type="text/css">
    body{background-color:#000}
</style>
```

...but on my application it still resulted in a momentary white flash

Answer (score 0):

While this is a pretty old question, hopefully this can help someone else who stumbles along (like me):

Using some javascript seems to have worked for me (only tested on Firefox 84.0 - Ubuntu):

### index.html:

```
<script src='script.js'></script>
```

### script.js:

```
onload = function() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the most efficient way to accomplish this is to place the background color in the html tag itself in the main document file. Such that

```
<html lang="en" style="background-color: #111">
```

With this you can set any background color you want and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Setting [`color-scheme: dark light;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color-scheme) style on the root html element or a color-scheme [meta tag](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/color-scheme/#aa-theres-a-corresponding-meta-tag-too) appears to do the trick for avoiding the white flash for users with dark mode set. This tells the browser that the page is suitable for both light and dark mode, so it knows that it can use the darkmode UA (user agent) styles which includes a dark background color.

Unfortunately, the browser can only know this after the html is fetched and parsed, so it works especially well on SPA apps where the initial index.html is tiny, the page is already cached, or it's going through a fast CDN. All the other solutions here have the same issues, and it would take browsers setting the default color to dark - which they wouldn't be able to do for compatibility reasons, or a browser extension to be able to avoid the bright flash before the index.html loads in.

The benefit to using `color-scheme` over just setting a background is that for light mode viewers, it won't flash a dark color.

The downsides (or maybe upside, depending) is that it will change how the browser renders various built-in elements to fit the appropriate theme the user/developer desires. [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/color-scheme/) has some examples of that. The snippet below shows that for an `input`, it changes to a dark background.

Note that the snippet itself will flash bright while the iframe is rendering, which shows the issue with any of the html/css/js solutions to this problem.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="color-scheme" content="dark light">
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" value="dark!" />
  <input type="text" style="color-scheme: light" value="light!" />
</body>

</html>
```