# Avoid showing the browser's default white background when loading

Tags: html, css

The background of my site is black.

Every time the site reloads the browser's window blinks because the default setting of browser binary is "white background" in Chrome & Firefox.

Is there an alternative, but rebuild whole browser from sources?

Related questions:

- [Set page load to black instead of white background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18937469/set-page-load-to-black-instead-of-white-background)
- [Flashing a White page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563484/flashing-a-white-page)

I'm already trying to use `<body background="#000">`. It doesn't help.

Is this an unresolvable problem?

Comment: The white background happens before anything on your page loads. IE, before the browser accesses anything on your webserver. That includes any directives to show the screen as black, if that were even possible.

Comment: There are cookies. Browser remember that link was used or not. As Hardy answer me, there is cache. I believe that this problem was solved without DOM/Ajax ten years ago. I can't find answer.

Comment: Cookies are sent by your server. The white background shows up from the time the browser starts trying to connect to your website up until it receives something to tell it to do otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can try:

- Check that your website allows browser to cache it's content so pages loads faster after viewed once
- load resources (css, js, images) dynamically or bottom of body so the page is rendered faster (DOM)
- use AJAX to change content when navigating inside your site